# How to stick one html element to other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example:

```
<div style="background-color:black;width:20px;height:20px;" > </div>
<div style="background-color:red;width:20px;height:20px; margin:50px;" > </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TLLup/

Here is two bars red and black. 
I want to stick black bar to red and black bar must follow to red if it changes coordinates and it doesn't matter what we are doing changes DOM or just using jquery function `$(element).position()`.

Comment: Could you not just wrap the two divs in another div, then move that around?

Comment: No, that's not very realistic - you'll have to manually change the position of the black when you change position of red. There's no "position changed" event. On a side note, you can use float and remove the margin to make them stick initially ([jsFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/TLLup/4/)) but I guess you already know that.

Comment: As @Polynomial said... why not wrap them together?

Comment: @Polynomial Unfortunally i cannt do it.

Comment: something related: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/monitoring-dom-properties/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `float: left;` to the black box, either by modifying the `style=""` attribute [or via jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using html5 canvas for any custom drawing.

Here is an example that shows you how to draw lines.

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-tutorial/

As long as the dots are on the canvas you should be able to listen for their mouse events and draw a line with the canvas.